# ASP.Net MVC - strange params caching behaviour in Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, binding, action

I'm facing a strange problem in my project. My actions are getting old param values instead of the actual values which are in Request.Params. I created a HomeController.Echo(string text) action to illustrate it (see screenshot). When I call the action for the first time like "Home/Echo?text=aaa" everything works fine. When I call the same action second time with different text value ("Home/Echo/text=bbb"), I get the old "aaa" value again in my action "text" parameter. Strange think is that Request.Params contains the right "bbb" value.

I'm thinking if there's something I could break myself, but can't figure out anything. I'm serving controllers from IoC container, I overrided ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters method (to inject dependencies into filters from IoC) and I'm handling HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest. Im'not working with params/binding anyhow in any of these...

[screenshot](http://i.nyx.cz/files/00/00/02/14/214301_e613dda0904e56e02677.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by some threading issues probably - I forgot to register controllers in my IoC container with per-request lifecycle (they were registered as singletons).

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged through the application to see where the value is getting switched out. A simple watch on the text variable (whatever you call it in the code) should yield where the variable gets changed. Without code to run through, I have no clue where it is happening.

I would say write a test, but there is still a possibility of UI interfering here. If you find where in the code it is changing, then write a test to confirm the bug and start whacking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start commenting all the methods you overrode until you isolate the problem. In worst case you will get to the point where the ASP.NET MVC wizard left your project when you created it and where parameter binding definitely worked.

Comment: It looks like it's caused by MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorControllerFactory which I'm using for providing controllers from IoC container. The parameters work ok when I comment out ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory() row. I'll try to find out some more details...